# CSS Selector Specificity Calculation: Class Versus Elements

Tags: html, css, angular

Given the following CSS and HTML, why does it produce a blue background?

```css
div div { background-color: blue }
.myClass { background-color: green }
```

```html
<div>
  neither green nor blue
  <div class="myClass">
     should be green but is blue
  </div>
</div>
```

If I understand selector calculation correctly, the first rule should evaluate to 0:0:2, while the second should evaluate to 0:1:0.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity mentions inherited styles being overridden, but this is a direct application of class on the div, not an inherited style.  What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
I am working in Angular 8, and here's a screenshot of the thing that's been confounding me.  So...since this works outside of Angular, is this somehow an Angular issue?
[image: strange css]

Here's the devtools console, showing the override and the css rules...
[image]

Comment: Your understanding is correct, it should indeed be green, [and it is for me...](https://jsfiddle.net/w19zjgus/)

Comment: Not into angular at all, but from your screenshot you can see that the rules have been rewritten to include an attribute selector, which makes them the same specificity as class, so it becomes 0:2:0

Comment: @Kaiido, thank you, that confirms it for me! :) I realized after I posted the second screenshot and I'm glad to finally understand correctly the reasons (and to have positive confirmation).

Comment: Probably their mean of doing style scoping.

Answer (score 1):

After looking closely at the CSS style calculations in the second image, I think I realize now what's going on.  If someone can confirm this, I'd appreciate it.  The generated CSS

```
div[_ngcontent-xpy-c52] div[_ngcontent-xpy-c52] {
```

appears to have attributes attached.  Those attributes ratchet up the class score of the `div div` rule, making it override the `.myClass` rule.  Even though the original CSS does NOT contain those attributes, what basically every browser sees is what I have quoted here, and so the outcome at runtime is quite different from what one would otherwise expect.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUyMV.png)

Your code worked correct. Here my code.

```
<style>
div div { background-color: blue }
.myClass { background-color: green }
</style>

<div>
  neither green nor blue
  <div class="myClass">
     should be green but is blue
  </div>
</div>
```